# Getting a weird filenotfoundexception

Tags: java, android, android-file

I am currently on the beginner level when it comes to Android & I am currently scratching my head over an issue that I am currently facing.

I am creating an Android app to check if "cache.json" exists in the internal storage:

- If it does not exist then first create it & write a string fetched from HTTP API to the file (replaced with fixed string in code below).
- Regardless, read the file after writing is done (if necessary) & do appropriate stuff.

This is the code snippet:

```
public class ShowClasses extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        filename = "cache.json";
        file = new File(getApplicationContext().getFilesDir(), filename);

        if (file.exists()) {
            System.out.println("EXISTS");
        } else {
            System.out.println("DOES NOT EXIST");
            writeFile();
        }

        readFile();
    }

    public void writeFile() {
        new JsonTask().execute(email);
    }

    public void readFile() {
        FileInputStream fin = null;
        try {
            fin = new FileInputStream(file);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int c;
        result = "";
        try {
            while( (c = fin.read()) != -1){
                result = result + Character.toString((char)c);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try {
            fin.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return;
    }

    private class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            result = ""; // Clear result
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd.setMessage("Please wait");
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            return "THIS STRING IS GOING TO BE RETURNED " + params[0];
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);    

            try {
                file.createNewFile();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            FileOutputStream fileout = null;

            try {
                fileout = new FileOutputStream(file);
                fileout.write(result.getBytes());
                //display file saved message
                msg("File saved successfully!");

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                fileout.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (pd.isShowing()){
                pd.dismiss();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I have tried to remove un-necessary part of the code so that it is smaller in length.

The actual issue I am facing is when writeFile() & readFile() both are called. I get a FileNotFoundException in readFile() when I open the stream even though the file should be created since writeFile() is called before readFile().

If I writeFile on one execution & then call readFile() on the other, it simply works as it should be.

This is the error that I am facing.

> System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/user/0/host.timetable.timetablenotifier/files/cache.json (No such file or directory)
>   System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`writeFile()` is asynchronous. When that method returns, *nothing has happened* with respect to this file. At most, `onPreExecute()` of your `JsonTask` might be called. So, when you call `readFile()`, the file will not exist yet.

Beyond that:

- You have an `AsyncTask` that you use in `writeFile()`, but you do your disk I/O in `onPostExecute()`, and that method is called on the main application thread.
- You are doing disk I/O on the main application thread in `readFile()`.
- You catch exceptions, log them, but then continue executing your code, when most of those exceptions mean that the later statements are going to fail as well.
- Reading in data one `int` at a time has not been a recommended approach for getting close to 20 years, for performance reasons.
- You will have multiple issues related to configuration changes, such as screen rotations, as neither your `AsyncTask` nor your `ProgressDialog` account for configuration changes

Also:

- `getApplicationContext().getFilesDir()` could be replaced by `getFilesDir()` in `onCreate()`
- You do not need `createNewFile()`

Comment: I really didn't think about AsyncTask being asynchronous & all these. And you are absolutely right about unhandled exceptions, I am currently just getting my way around how to do my current task and once I am done, I will write everything from scratch keeping all the measures in mind.

Comment: And it worked well when I moved readFile() in the Asynctask, it was actually there but I kept that in onCreate() to remove redundancy. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`AsyncTask` runs in a background thread so the other code in the main thread doesn't wait for the execution to complete. In simpler terms, your `readFile()` method is executed before `writeFile()` completes and hence there is a `FileNotFoundException`. What would work for you is if you put the `readFile()` method at the end of the `onPostExecute()` method inside your `Asynctask`

Comment: Thanks mate, it did the job. I really didn't consider that.